# Include Formatting Save As .nb to .m

Tags: format

Is there a way to export `Input` Cells in my current notebook(.nb) as a .m file while including indents?

For example if my notebook contains

```
Print[
  23
]
```

The .m should ideally contain

```
Print[
  23
]
```

with formatting.  [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/converting-a-notebook-to-plain-text-programmatically) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-a-selected-cell-as-plain-text/1411#1411) are related but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following creates a duplicate notebook before temporarily exporting the text.  It removes all output cells.

```
CleanNotebook[nb_: SelectedNotebook[], 
   styles_: {"Output", 
     "Print"}] := (NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellStyle];
     NotebookDelete[nb];) & /@ styles;
nbExport[n_, new_: ""] := 
  Module[{loc, nb}, 
   loc = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "output.txt"}];
   nb = CreateDocument[n, Visible -> False];
   CleanNotebook[nb];
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "Save", {loc, "Text"}]];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   (*ret=StringReplace["\n"<>Import[loc,"Text"],"\nIn["~~
   ShortestMatch[___]~~"]:= "\[Rule]""];*)NotebookClose[nb];
   If[new != "", CopyFile[loc, new];];
   Return[Import[loc]]];
```

Convert current nb to text.

```
nbExport[NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]][[1]]];
```

Or convert BoxData to text.

```
nbExport[{Cell[
   BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "\[IndentingNewLine]", RowBox[{"+", "1"}]}]], 
   "Input"]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it fit your needs?

```
Print[
  23
]
```

*cell break*

```
cell = NotebookRead @ Experimental`PreviousCell[];
DumpSave["test", cell]
```

You don't have to use `PreviousCell`, it is just handy here.

```
ClearAll[cell]
<< test
CellPrint @ cell
```

Comment: +1.  But I really would like the file to be human readable and indented similar to if you manually indented the file on the Wolfram WorkBench or another text editor.  To me this although is nice, it doesn't really have any advantages over saving something as a notebook only to copy the notebook cells out of the notebook to restore formatting.