# AutoGeneratedPackage Formatting

Tags: export, notebooks, packages

If you do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`o` you open an option inspector.

And then you can enable `AutoPackageGenerated` which allows you to automatically generate .m from .nb input.

Unfortunately as discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63445/include-formatting-save-as-nb-to-m) the outputted .m is not formatted.

How might I patch such?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by not formatted?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I am just referring to the spaces/indention on each line.

Comment: ok. That is because the default style is Code. Just modify that style to whatever you need. If you need help to do that then browse some of the related questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only exports output cells, but does work.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> 
    Module[{loc, nb, new = FileNameJoin@Append[
         Drop[FileNameSplit@NotebookFileName[], -1],
         FileBaseName@FileNameTake[NotebookFileName[]] <> ".m"
         ]
      },
     NotebookSave[InputNotebook[]];
     loc = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "output.txt"}]; 
     nb = 
      CreateDocument[NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]][[1]], 
       Visible -> False];
     FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "Save", {loc, "Text"}]];
     NotebookClose[nb];
     DeleteFile[new];
     CopyFile[loc, new];
     ]
   }]
```