# How to make a flowchart?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, style

I'd like to make a flow chart in similar to this:
[image]

I think it's more of a layout and stylistic question for a graph - how to style a graph with labeled edges and vertices so that it looks like a chart?

Examples:

- [www.draw.io](http://www.draw.io)

Comment: It's entirely possible with enough VertexShapeFunction and EdgeShapeFunction settings, but it's also a lot of work and very tedious.  Why don't you use a dedicated diagramming tool?  You could do it in a tenth of the time.  No, probably a hundredth of the time.

Comment: Although Mathematica's graphics functions should be able to draw all this, and the graph drawing routines have quite some flexibility, I don't think Mathematica is a good tool for this. There are several (even free) programs that would be a better choice.

Comment: If you just want a static figure, you can define graphs, rectangles, text, arrows and such.  But if you're a serious *Mathematica* user, you want your figures to *compute*.  For this, see `QueueingNetworkProcess`.

Comment: So, do you have an example you want to style in such way. And if so, where have you failed?

Comment: I would love to have graph gui functionality... And with the addition of all the mesh capabilities, I think that we are currently missing both 2d and 3d input on a Graphics space...

Comment: I know you've already thought about this before - see [Controlling TreePlot (and GraphPlot) layout issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6388/245); but in all its generality this question seems a bit too much work to fit into a single answer... Just another idea without graphs: perhaps one could adapt [Circuit drawing in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8614/245) to your purposes. Someone has to put in the effort, though...