# How to make circuit-like diagrams

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, charts

I was reading through a [blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and found some really nice graphs, and I was wondering how to generate similar ones with Mathematica:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could perhaps use this as a starting point: [Circuit drawing in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8614/245). Although your question isn't about circuits but "circuit-like diagrams", the general drawing methods would work analogously here. However, to get a useful answer you should narrow down what specific difficulty you have in coding this yourself.

Comment: There is an example, with input code, on the new-in-10 page: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-graphs-and-networks/analyze-an-electric-circuit.html However there is no description of how this Graph was created, and I am not aware of any free circuit building packages for *Mathematica*.  There are also a number of demonstrations under the topic [circuit design](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=circuit+design) that may be of interest.  I feel that unless someone has an existing package to post this question is **too broad** and needs to be narrowed.

Comment: You should also check out WRI's SystemModeler software, it has [circuit-drawing and modelling capacity](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/examples/more/physics/chuass-circuit).

Comment: See also [Controlling TreePlot (and GraphPlot) layout issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6388/245)