# Rasterize is influenced by WindowSize of the notebook where I run it

Tags: rasterize

The two images show what I mean:

[image: the tow images are generated with different size even if the code is the same]

Actually, the problem I have is that I need the images as in the second case, that's the whole expression in one row. In realty, the code is even more complex and is executed by the kernel calling UsingFrontEnd (it is under a webMathematica application) so, I cannot set manually the WindowSize as in the second example. 
If you want to try, the code is:

```
Rasterize[TraditionalForm[Log[Sqrt[x^2]](x - x^3)/(y + y^2) + 1/(y - y^2)], 
          "Image", RasterSize -> 800]
```

Run inside a notebook changing the window size and see the difference. 
I used Mathematica 9.0 but is seems to be the same with 10.0.2
Any workaround?

Comment: I think you're looking for `ImageSize -> 800`.

Comment: No, ImageSize has the same effect, it changes the size of the resulting image but the expression inside is still broken into two lines.

Comment: Related: [(6361)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6361/121)

Answer (score 7):

**Edit (23/02/15) : V10 & V9**

### V10

It seems that the new (**v10**) option [`ImageFormattingWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFormattingWidth.html) is what you are looking for.
In your case, I get the same graphic whatever the size of the window is if I write :

```
Rasterize[
 TraditionalForm[
  Log[Sqrt[x^2]] (x - x^3)/(y + y^2) + 1/(y - y^2)], "Image", 
 RasterSize -> 800, ImageFormattingWidth -> Infinity]
```

As I understand from the docs, `ImageFormattingWidth` seems to play the same role than [`PageWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PageWidth.html) which controls linebreaking. In order to prevent any linebreaking in the expression you want to `Rasterize`, it seems reasonable to set the option to `Ìnfinity`.

### V9

There is no `ImageFormattingWidth` option in `Rasterize` : linebreaking is done according the current `WindowSize` of the notebook. The workaround is then to `Rasterize` the object automatically in another notebook where `WindowSize` or `PageWidth` have been carefully chosen.

Here, I directly adapted the approach/code given by **@szabolcs,@halirutan** for a similar problem (see this **[post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32211/19960)**.)

In particular, instead of defining a `WindowSize` for the invisible Notebook where the expression will be rasterized, I just set `PageWidth->Infinity` to prevent any non expected linebreaking (like in v10, see above).
Then, as @halirutan, I use `Rasterize` to rasterize directly the invisible notebook where was sent the object to be rasterized (i did not know it was possible to rasterize a notebook, see the *applications* section in the [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) docs.)

```
rasterize[myexpr_, mysize_, pad_: 0] := 
 Module[{nb, mg}, 
  nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[myexpr, FontWeight -> Plain], 
    Visible -> False, PageWidth -> Infinity];
  mg = Rasterize[nb, "Image", 
    RasterSize -> Switch[pad, 1, {mysize, {mysize}}, _, mysize]]; 
  NotebookClose[nb];
  Return@mg]
```

(*the optional `pad` argument is to try to force `Rasterize` to get an image with the exact width size as requested. Actually I noticed that it will actually try do so by padding the image with extra space. See the example below*)

**Tests**

```
expr = Log[Sqrt[x^2]] (x - x^3)/(y + y^2) + 1/(y - y^2);

stylexpr = TraditionalForm[expr];
```

**I get the same images whatever the size of my working notebook window is.**

```
rasterize[stylexpr, 1200]
ImageDimensions@%
```

[image]

```
rasterize[stylexpr, 1200, 1]
ImageDimensions@%
```

[image]

```
stylexpr = 
  TraditionalForm[
   Style[expr, Bold, FontFamily -> "Chalkboard", Red]];
rasterize[stylexpr, 1200]
ImageDimensions@%
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it goes to the right direction. Unfortunately it's in 10 and I have to run 9. I hope someone might suggest a workaround for it in 9. Anyhow, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I read many other questions without having anything of similar, but it could be I missed the right one.

Comment: @bobknight Unfortunately it's very easy to miss questions in the search.  I find a web of linked questions often easier to navigate, hence my efforts with all the **Related:** links.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the link, frankly I read that one but I thought it is a different situation. There the problem is due to Save As whereas I run Rasterize and it's not clear why the WindowSize of the working notebook should affect the final image breakdown. It seems there is a influence between RasterSize (but the same with ImageSize) and the WindowSize. And in the 6361 I cannot see any workaround suitable for Rasterize. I'll try to read it once again.

Comment: @bobknight No, it's not a duplicate.  Please don't waste your time.  It's linked for other visitors who find this question and not that one, or the other way around.  (I removed the "possible duplicate" from my comment after reading it again.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks a lot

Comment: @SquareOne thanks for the effort and the additional solution. It works in v9 and at least it is a possible solution. Even if, my real code is more complex and it's hard to add all that steps just because Rasterize is influenced by WindowSize. I'm also waiting an answer from Wolfram and I hope they can provide something similar to the new option you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: @bobknight Please see my last edit with working solution for v9.