# What does copying Output cell using Copy As > Plain Text actually does?

Tags: export, import, copy-as

So, an input cell after evaluation gives an

```
In[X] := str1 = ...
Out[X]:= ....
```

If I right click on the right edge of the Out[X]'s cell, and select Copy As > Plain text  in the context menu, and then open a new text file in Emacs and paste it in.
Then I use `str2 = Import[file, "String"]`.  What is the difference between `str1` and `str2`? How do I get `str2` without using an external file?

Comment: You could try using `ExportString[]` along with `InputForm[]`.

Comment: Do you mean `InputForm[ExportString[str1]] === str2` is `True`? If not, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I was in the suspicion that Copy As > Plain text calls some FrontEnd function and is not always same as using some combination of kernel functions.

Comment: Is that what you are after? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5478