# Programmatically generate wolfram language script (.wls) file from notebook (.nb) files

Tags: front-end, notebooks, scripting

For a better integration with git version control, I'm looking for a way to programmatically generate .wls file from existing notebook .nb files, given the path to a specific notebook file `/path/to/foo.nb`, preferably from a command line interface via `wolframscript`. `NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], "test.wls"]` does not work and saves the file as a normal notebook named "test.nb".

Also tried: this is achievable via file>save as...>choose format .wls; however, `FrontEndTokenExecute["SaveRename"]` only brings up the 'save as...' dialogue, not able to programmatically set the output format as wls or click save.

Comment: Maybe use ExportPacket: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/363

Comment: For completeness, run `FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  "Save", {StringDrop[NotebookFileName[], -2] <> "wls", "Script"}]]`