# How can I programmatically extract the text content from a Notebook's cell definition?

Tags: notebooks, cells, boxes

Given the Notebook cell definition below from the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Bob) as an example:

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{"Clear", "[", "Bob", "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"Options", "[", "Bob", "]"}], "=", 
   RowBox[{"{", 
    RowBox[{"UpdateInterval", "\[Rule]", "0.05"}], "}"}]}], ";"}], "\n", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr_", ",", 
    RowBox[{"opts", ":", 
     RowBox[{"OptionsPattern", "[", "]"}]}]}], "]"}], ":=", 
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr", ",", "1", ",", "1", ",", "opts"}], "]"}]}], "\n", 
 RowBox[{See
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr_", ",", "rate_", ",", 
    RowBox[{"opts", ":", 
     RowBox[{"OptionsPattern", "[", "]"}]}]}], "]"}], ":=", 
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr", ",", "rate", ",", "1", ",", "opts"}], "]"}]}], "\n", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr_", ",", "Automatic", ",", "rest___"}], "]"}], ":=", 
  RowBox[{"Bob", "[", 
   RowBox[{"expr", ",", "1", ",", "rest"}], "]"}]}], "\n", 
 RowBox[{"Bob", "/:", 
  RowBox[{"MakeBoxes", "[", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{
     RowBox[{"HoldPattern", "[", "Bob", "]"}], "[", 
     RowBox[{"expr_", ",", "rate_", ",", "magnitude_", ",", 
      RowBox[{"OptionsPattern", "[", "Bob", "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", "form_"}], 
   "]"}], ":=", 
  RowBox[{"AdjustmentBox", "[", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"ToBoxes", "[", 
     RowBox[{"expr", ",", "form"}], "]"}], ",", 
    RowBox[{"BoxBaselineShift", "\[Rule]", 
     RowBox[{"Dynamic", "[", 
      RowBox[{"Refresh", "[", 
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{"magnitude", "*", 
         RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
          RowBox[{
           RowBox[{"N", "@", 
            RowBox[{"AbsoluteTime", "[", "]"}]}], "*", "rate"}], "]"}]}], ",", 
        RowBox[{"UpdateInterval", "\[Rule]", 
         RowBox[{"OptionValue", "[", 
          RowBox[{"Bob", ",", "UpdateInterval"}], "]"}]}]}], "]"}], "]"}]}]}],
    "]"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"ResourceFunction", "[", "\"\<FormatAsResourceFunction\>\"", "]"}], 
  "[", "Bob", "]"}]}], "Input",
 CellEventActions->{Inherited, {"KeyDown", "\t"} :> Replace[SelectionMove[
       SelectedNotebook[], After, Cell]; NotebookFind[
       SelectedNotebook[], "TabNext", Next, CellTags, AutoScroll -> True, 
       WrapAround -> True], Blank[NotebookSelection] :> SelectionMove[
       SelectedNotebook[], All, CellContents, AutoScroll -> True]], 
   PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> False},
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.7686653112660103`*^9, 3.768665313802607*^9}, {
  3.76866535043878*^9, 3.76866544731925*^9}, {3.768665643440073*^9, 
  3.76866568116868*^9}},
 CellTags->"TabNext",
 CellLabel->"In[17]:=",
 CellID->778396829]
}, Open  ]],
```

**How can I *programmatically* extract the text content from a Notebook's cell definition?**

Few remarks:

- The goal is to write a script part of a toolchain to convert from notebooks to a text format more suitable for integration with my website engine. I'm primarily concerned with cells containing plain text or Wolfram Language source code.
- I initially considered extracting the cell's content as a string. But extracting it as an `InputForm` might be more suitable.
- By *programmatically*, I understand the conversion could run unattended on a developer kernel, without requiring a front-end and without user interaction. For example, most answers in a previous question ([How do I extract the contents of a selected cell as plain text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5478)) are using the clipboard, a solution that shouldn't<sup>1</sup> be suitable for my needs.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> As far as I understand it at least</sub>

Comment: That's it: [How do I extract the contents of a selected cell as plain text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5478), right?

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba. I saw that question, but as far as I understood it, it is based on the assumption we run in an interactive environment. And the answers use the front-end capabilities and the clipboard. I was more looking for something based on the core language that could run unattended from a "script" running on a developer kernel.

Comment: @Kuba: I've edited the question to give more context and to explain why I think it's a different question.

Comment: "it is based on the assumption we run in an interactive environment" No, this is a misunderstanding. It works fine in command line mode. It does use a Front End process (so you may need `UsingFrontEnd`), but it does not require that you use Mathematica through the notebook interface. The Front End is an essential components that is _always_ part of the Wolfram Engine, even of the free version which does not support the notebook interface.

Comment: @Szabolcs I deleted my comment where I claimed FE is not available in WS, I was certain it is the case.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you far that clarification. From the last paragraph of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExecutingNotebookCommandsDirectlyInTheFrontEnd.html, I thought the front end was only available when running Mathematica in "interactive mode"

Comment: @Kuba I was just going to double check that :-) We couldn't export graphics without the FE, so it really is essential to may operations.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Somthing as simple as `Export["foo.png", Graphics@Circle[]]` causes a slave FE process to be started in the background (without any visible windows).

Comment: Anyway, given FE is there and the background of the question maybe `NotebookImport` will be more handy?

Comment: Indeed @Kuba. I had little concern about reading the notebook _par se_. From your comment I assume [NotebookImport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookImport.html?view=all)  is FE-dependant. I didn't realized that by reading the doc.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Kuba you gave me a lot of ideas and things to try this afternoon. Thanks a lot! If that's ok for you, I will post an answer quoting your comments if I manage to make some progress with this issue.

Comment: Sure :) p.s. make sure your use case fits the license for the free engine or whatever you are using.