# Revert Notebook to earlier version using Notebook History

Tags: front-end, history

Is it possible to revert a notebook to its earlier version via the Mathematica's [Notebook History panel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookHistoryDialog.html)?

It would be nice if I could select a point in time in the bottom graph and revert back to that version:

[image]

When hovering over the blue dots on the upper graph, you can see the previous and the current contents of the changed cells, so Mathematica must store this somewhere.

Maybe this could even be used instead of [a better undo implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/implementing-efficient-multiple-undo).

Comment: This won't be useful for the undo functionality, because this only tracks the `CellChangeTimes` and not individual keystrokes...

Comment: @rm-rf I would at any time prefer whole cell reverts over Mathematica's undo functionality.