# How to syntax highlight a code cell in another language?

Tags: notebooks, code-organization

I'm learning c/c++/objective-c and I wanted to write my notes in a mathematica notebook. But without the proper syntax color highlighting it looks terrible....

Comment: Sorry, Mathematica doesn't support pluggable syntax coloring modules.

Comment: Then mathematica is not the one language to rule them all

Comment: Something that comes very close is this: [Customizing syntax highlighting for private cell styles](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles)