# Using \n (new line) as delimiter in StringSplit

Tags: string-manipulation

While trying to build my own simple C-language highlighter for strings in Mathematica ([see here for a very sophisticated highlighter generator package by Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles)) I came upon the issue of using `\n` (line delimiter) as a delimiter in `StringSplit`. Manually delimiting a string with `\n` or formatting in the front-end (as done below) both result in a string delimited with `\n` at the appropriate place as can be seen by looking at the `FullForm`.

```
str = "Hello World 
2016"  
(* Hello World
   2016 *)

str // FullForm 
(*Hello World \n2016*)
```

This is however not recognized by `StringSplit`:

```
StringSplit[str, {Whitespace -> "Whitespace", "\n" -> "Newline"}] 
(* {"Hello", "Whitespace", "World", "Whitespace", "2016"} *)
```

The expected output would be:

```
{"Hello", "Whitespace", "World", "Whitespace", "Newline", "2016"}
```

Is there a special symbol like `Whitespace` or any other way to represent `\n` so that `StringSplit` accepts it as a delimiter?

Comment: Take a look at what `Whitespace` ref page says.

Comment: `StringSplit[str, {" " .. -> "Whitespace", "\n" -> "Newline"}]`

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks! In the light of the clear documentation on `Whitespace` this turned out to be a stupid question ...once again an example of dangerous "intuition" and the suggestive nature of the naming scheme of build-in symbols

Comment: `StringSplit["abba", "b"]` gives empty string from between `"b"s`. Shouldn't it be the case for your `" \\n"`? If so, maybe: `{"\n" -> "Newline", WhitespaceCharacter -> "Whitespace"}`?