# How to TYPE other programming languages in a text cell?

Tags: front-end, formatting

I like to discuss a Python script in a Mathematica text cell (not execute it). How should I go about that since a copied and pasted text looks very ugly, especially without proper indentation and color coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer:

There is nothing out of the box to support other languages.

Style/format text manually or write a parser like here: [Customizing syntax highlighting for private cell styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1315/5478).

p.s. Format / Style / `"Program"` looks better for code.